# Running FFT (Fast Fourier Transfomation) in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

How can I run FFT(Fast Fourier Transformation) on a raster image in ArcMap?

I can run FFT in Erdas, but for that I need to convert from tif to img, get Erdas FFT internal format and transform it into  img and apply the filter, then reverse the whole process ... it is to much redundancy...

I don't know if/how I can run FFT through a script etc in ArcMap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but I don't believe that ArcMap can perform Fast Fourier Transforms. At least not out of the box. If you are comfortable using python, you can take advantage of the **[numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/index.html)** module which comes installed with ArcMap.

If you convert your raster to a numpy array using **[RasterToNumpyArray](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm)**, there are a number of tools available to perform FFT within numpy.  You can check them out **[here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.fft.html)**.

Then you can convert your processed numpy array back to a raster using **[NumpyArrayToRaster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/numpyarraytoraster-function.htm)**.